# Pass data using jQuery AJAX call into function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to call back function PHP in AJAX. But it not working for me, is it correct the code below? Any help i will appreciate it, thank you!

> JavaScript AJAX call

```
//AJAX call for button
    $("#primaryTextButton").kendoButton();
    var button = $("#primaryTextButton").data("kendoButton");
    button.bind("click", function(e) {

    var test = $("#dropdown").val()

    $.ajax({
        url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/testjson.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: function(){
                return {
                    method: "getAddTemplate", 
                        }
            },
                success: function (respond) {
                // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                 
                kendo.alert('Success'); // alert notification
                },
        });
    });
```

> PHP function (testjson.php)

```
function addTemplate(){
global $ehorsObj;
$employeeID = $_SESSION['employeeID'];
$propertyID = $_SESSION['propertyID'];
$hrsPositionID  = (isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '');
$programID      = (isset($_POST['progid']) ? $_POST['progid'] : '');
//  $id = $_POST['id'];
//  $progid = $_POST['progid'];

for($x=0; $x< sizeof($progid); $x++ )
{
$array = array();   
$sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM tblHrsPositionProgramTemplate WHERE hrsPositionID = '".$id."'
                AND programID = '".$progid[$x]."'";

$GetResult = $ehorsObj->FetchData($sqlSelect, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);

        $positionTemplateID = $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK("tblHrsPositionProgramTemplate"); 
        $sqlAdd = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tblHrsPositionProgramTemplate 
                    SET positionTemplateID = '" . $positionTemplateID . "',
                    programID = '" . $progid[$x] . "',
                    hrsPositionID  = '" . $id . "',
                    propertyID   = '" . $propertyID . "',
                    employeeID  = '" . $employeeID . "',
                    dateTimeEmployee = NOW() ,
                    active = 'y' ";     
        $ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlAdd, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);

        $positionTemplateIDLog = $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK("tblHrsPositionProgramTemplateLog");   
        $sqlAddLog = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tblHrsPositionProgramTemplateLog 
                    SET positionTemplateIDLog = '" . $positionTemplateIDLog . "',
                    positionTemplateID = '" . $positionTemplateID . "',
                    programID = '" . $progid[$x] . "',
                    hrsPositionID  = '" . $id . "',
                    propertyID   = '" . $propertyID . "',
                    employeeID  = '" . $employeeID . "',
                    dateTimeEmployee = NOW(),
                    active = 'y' "; 
        $ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlAddLog, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);
    }}
```

I want to call function addTemplate into AJAX call. How do I call the method "getAddTemplate". I'm really want to know if there is any code is wrong. Or I'm missing something. Thank you!

Comment: Your ajax send request the `testing.php`, while your PHP named `testjson.php`

Comment: My bad, I will update my new code.

Comment: I have updated my code above @catcon. Can you look again on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer that solve my problem. Hope can help the others!

```
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/testjson.php",
                        data: {
                                method: "deleteTemplate" ,
                                id: test,
                                progid: array
                                },
                    //  data: {'id':test,'progid':array},
                        success: function(){
                            kendo.alert("Data updated");
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly call PHP's function from Javascript. You have to call the PHP function inside PHP

```
<?php
function yourPhpFunction() {
 // Definition here
}

yourPhpFunction();
```

Comment: Can you show the code based on my code? I have update the code above.

Answer (score 0):

you should send the function name of controller with full path, check this!

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseUrl + 'invoices/order/searchServiceByProvider',
    data: {
        extra_service_id: extra_service_id
    },
    success: function (response) {
     var data = response.data;
     order.push(data);
    }
 });
```

So, in the url I send the full path of my controller with the name function and finally get the response on success property the ajax method.

Comment: Why do you send the data that way?

Comment: you should send the url something like this:  url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/testjson/addTemplate",

Comment: I have changed it but no data inserting into database